# Select all xml exclude a single specific node SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a column that stores xml using SQL Server's Xml data type. Also, I have an Xpath query that can select the single node from the xml that I am wanting to remove. So, my question is, is there a way to select all of the xml in the column EXCEPT the single specific node I'm needing to remove? I can select the node I want to remove, but I can't find a way to remove it from the rest of the xml and leave all the rest intact. If anyone could give me any guidance on how to do this using SQL Server Xml function, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = YourXmlField
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 1

SET @xml.modify('delete /Root/A')
SELECT @xml
```

So, you need to put the value into an XML variable and use modify to delete the node, giving the appropriate XPath for the node to remove.

Comment: thanks for responding!  I tried what you said and I got this error:  Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.  Here is the line of XQuery code I'm using that produces the error: pXml.modify('delete /variation/section/layout/area[@type = "Image" and @mode = "logo" and contains(@previewimage, ".jpg")]')

Comment: Did you try the *exact* approach I gave, using an XML variable? You get that error when you are using "modify" in the wrong way - e.g. if you try to do that directly in your SELECT. You can only use it as part of an UPDATE..SET statement, or as part of a SET on an XML variable.

Comment: BRILLIANT!  You're right, i was using it in a select statement.  I modified according to what you said and it works perfectly!